# How Shiro can protect JSF-2 page from unprotected page without login?

Tags: jsf-2, shiro

I try to set up Apache Shiro to JSF 2 pages.
I want to protect page1 but I can reach it without login from the unprotected home.xhtml.
From page1.xhtml with redirect I get to the loginpage.xhtml. (As defined)

If logged in it works fine.

It looks not the target but the 'from' page is supervised.
How do I have to modify shiro.ini to set
home.xhtml available without login AND page1.xhtml NOT available without login?

## shiro.ini .....

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /faces/loginpage.xhtml
//authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter - It was the same without REM
securityManager.rememberMeManager.cookie.name = demoRememberMe
[users]
a = q
[roles]
a = *

[urls]
/home.xhtml = anon
/loginpage.xhtml = authc
/page1.xhtml = authc
/protected.xhtml = authc
/faces/home.xhtml = anon
/faces/loginpage.xhtml = authc
/faces/page1.xhtml = authc
/faces/protected.xhtml = authc
/** = anon
```

home.xhtml:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{navigationController.moveToPage1}"  value="Page 1" >
```

page1.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
         <h:head>
      <title>BEMO - Page 1</title>      
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"  />   
   </h:head>
      <h:form>
         <h:commandButton action="home?faces-redirect=true"
            value="Back To Home Page" />
      </h:form>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: Consider reading this article : http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html

Comment: Done before too. Done again, put also
user.loginUrl = /faces/loginpage.xhtml to it but it did not help